# Can't get Nested JSON Object Property Typescript

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, api

I want to get CAD value from https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest
I have already used so many types of code, and it says that `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'CAD' of undefined"`
Really need your help, thank you very much.

It outputted all the Currencies if I console this code

```
((this.state.data as any).rates)
```

but when i want to get CAD currencies, it says the error

I have tried these codes :

```
((this.state.data as any).rates as any).CAD
(this.state.data as any)["Rates"]["CAD"];
(this.state.data as any)["Rates"].CAD;
```

The way I get the data is

```
interface IState {
  data?: object | null;
  isCurrency?: boolean;
  Currency?: string;
  Rate?: number;
}

export default class Header extends Component<{}, IState> {
  service: UserService = new UserService();
  state = {
    isCurrency: false,
    Currency: "USD",
    Rate: 1,
    data: [] = []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let result = await this.service.getAllCurrency();
    this.setState({
      data: (result as Pick<IState, keyof IState>).data
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

1.4591 (Based on the latest API)

Comment: How are you decoding the JSON into the object? Some methods decrypt a single level and others do the whole thing. Knowing the method you chose will help us answer your question.

Comment: 1. for Typescript, if you find the need to cast to `any`, you probably have a problem 2. examine the data in the debugger or with a `console.log`. It seems like the data is not in the place you think it is.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a type for your data. Because it's coming from an external source, typescript cannot infer that. Then parse your JSON and cast it to that type.

```
// Create a type for the expernal data.
interface Data {
    rates: {
        [currency: string]: number
    }
    base: string
    date: string
}

// Result of `JSON.parse()` will be `any`, since typescript can't parse it.
const untypedData = JSON.parse(`{
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.4591,
    "HKD": 8.6851,
    "ISK": 135.9,
    "PHP": 56.797,
    "DKK": 7.4648
  },
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2019-07-25"
}`)

// Cast the untyped JSON to the type you expect it to be.
const data: Data = untypedData

// Use the data according to it's type.
alert(data.rates.CAD)
```

[Working demo on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)